# Why is the Bootstrap-3 Modal not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

```html
<div class='container row'>
  <div style='padding-top:2em;' class='col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4'>
    <img data-toggle='modal' href='#modal-id' src='img/".$row_now[' image ']."' alt='No Image Uplaoded' class='img-thumbnail img-responsive' />
  </div>
  <div class='modal fade' id='modal-id'>
    <div class='modal-dialog'>
      <div class='modal-content'>
        <div class='modal-header'>
          <button type='button' class='close' data-dismiss='modal' aria-hidden='true'>&times;</button>
          <h4 class='text-primary modal-title'>".$row_now['title']."</h4>
        </div>
        <div class='modal-body'>
          <img src='img/".$row_now[' image ']."' alt='No Image Uplaoded' class='img-responsive' />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class='col-md-offset-1 col-sm-offset-1 col-xs-offset-1 col-md-7 col-sm-7 col-xs-7'>
    <h2 class='text-left text-primary'>".$row_now['title']."</h2>
    <p class='text-left' style='color:white;'>".$row_now['body']."</p>
    <a href='http://".$row_now[' link ']."'>".$row_now['link']."</a>
    <h4 class='text-left'>Uploaded By: ".$row_now['uname']."</h4>

    <h4 class='text-left'>".$lite['phone']."</h4>
  </div>
</div>
```

my intention is to use the image as a trigger to open the modal . All I get is a faded screen which doesn't respond to any clicking and the only option I am left with is refreshing the pge

Answer (score 2):

Your missing the data target attribute, and you have an href on your image. Try replacing the image with the code below:

```
<a href="#" data-target="#modal-id" data-toggle='modal' ><img src='img/".$row_now['image']."' alt='No Image Uplaoded' class='img-thumbnail img-responsive' /></a>
```

Comment: but this image is in the modal-body why does this need to have all the attributes ? shouldn't it be the case with the image outside the modal ?

Comment: @SandeepGV Not that image, the one above. Line 3.

Answer (score 1):

The IMG tag doesn't have an `href` attribute. Try wrapping your `img` in an anchor tag `a` and as noted by @Mark, add the `data-target` attribute as well:

```
 <a data-toggle="modal" data-target='#modal-id'><img   src='img/".$row_now['image']."' alt='No Image Uplaoded' class='img-thumbnail img-responsive' /></a>
```

Comment: but this image is in the modal-body why does this need to have all the attributes ? shouldn't it be the case with the image outside the modal ?

Comment: This is the case with the image which is outside the modal body, in the div with classes `container row`.